# Keep toolbars from changing taskbar size

Tags: windows-7, taskbar, toolbar

When I set a toolbar in the taskbar to show large icons, it makes the taskbar taller. Is there any way to prevent this?

[image: taskbar buttons]

Comment: How exactly would that work? What do you expect it to look like then, have the large icons overflowing out of the Taskbar? If you want large icons, then the Taskbar has to get bigger to accommodate them.

Comment: Both my taskbar icons and my toolbar icons are 32 x 32, but when the toolbar is showing large icons, there is ~10 pixel gap between the bottom of the taskbar buttons and the bottom of the screen. EDIT: I added a picture now, see original post.

Comment: Yes, of course, because the Taskbar icons are still the same size. You should show your toolbar icons; I suspect that they *don’t* have a gap below them. Perhaps your question should be how to force the Taskbar buttons to dynamically resize to the Taskbar height.

Comment: The toolbar icons are centered vertically in the taskbar.

Comment: I'm confused. Could you post an image of the entire task bar? I may have read the question wrong, but as I understand it you have a toolbar installed. Does it appear on the right? Also, is it a third party toolbar?

Comment: I just tried it myself and it does indeed make the taskbar bigger.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [FreeLaunchBar](http://www.freelaunchbar.com/).

Add the toolbar to your taskbar, right click on it, and select FLB Settings...

- Metrics

  - Button Margins

    - Width: 20
    - Height: 0
- Icon Sizes

  - Make sure large icon size is 32

Add shortcuts.

Right click and select View --> Large Icons.

Answer (score 1):

To fix the vertical alignment of the taskbar you can edit the theme's MSSTYLES file in [msstyleEditor](https://github.com/nptr/msstyleEditor). To find the file, open the themes folder, usually `C:\Windows\Resources\Themes`, then the theme's subfolder, then open the msstyles file in msstyleEditor.

1. in `Class View`: expand `TaskBar::Toolbar`, then click `BUTTON`
2. in `Property View`: change `CONTENTMARGINS` to `0,0,0,0`
3. click another property to accept the edits
4. save in a new file with a different name

[image]

Replacing the msstyles file is a standard procedure:

1. take ownership of the original msstyles file if it's a built-in one
   (there are many instructions around)
2. switch your Windows theme to a different one
3. restart the explorer.exe process or use Unlocker utility or log off and log on again
   to unlock the original msstyles file
4. rename the original msstyles file (for example, add `original` to its name)
5. rename the modified msstyles file to the original file's name

Now activate the theme.